# Why only mono when opening sound settings with my headphones?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, settings, usb-c

I have a pair of Jabra Evolve2 85. I connect them wirelessly to a little USB-C dongle plugged into my Ubuntu 20.10 laptop. The headphones are recognized as a USB device and can be selected in sound output settings. They work just fine, but only until I open Sound settings. Then they immediately switch to mono and poorer sound quality and when I do the left <-> right test it's mono. As soon as I close Sound settings the headphones automatically switches back to stereo high quality sound. They also switch to this mono mode when I do Skype and Zoom calls. I seem to remember that when I use bluetooth headphones there's two modes in settings to choose from, one for chat and such, and one for high quality music. Maybe Ubuntu gets "confused" when I use these hybrid headphones that connect to a dongle which again is connected to the laptop? Things seem to work fine but this switch to mono when opening sound settings is very confusing.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Jabra2 Evolve 75 and the Jabra Link 380 USB-C dongle. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same. Jabra Link 380 USB and Evolve 85

Answer (score 0):

I have a Jabra Evolve2 65. It has two sound settings: you can choose between stereo without microphone or mono with microphone.

When you set the microphone to a non-Jabra one in the sound settings, like the laptop's built-in mic, then you have stereo sound. When you set the microphone to Jabra's mic, then you have mono sound.

I think that this is acceptable as soon as it is understood.